# 422 Unprocessable Entity in FastAPI when returning response

Tags: python, fastapi

I am using FastAPI for machine learning inference and returning response. There are two tasks that are controlled by `task_id`. For `task_id=0` both `solvent` and `solute` are required to return response when using `task_id=1` I only need `solute`. But when giving the values for the keys it is required to give `solvent` value in `task_id=1` where I don't need it. If not given the value I am getting `422 Unprocessable Entity`. Is their a way to do it, so that it won't throw the error, if solvent value is not provided when using `task_id=1`?

```py
@app.get('/predict')
async def predict(task_id:int, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks,solute,solvent):
    global task_id_global
    task_id_global = task_id
    if task_id == 0:
        background_tasks.add_task(predictions,solute,solvent)
        return {'success'}
    elif task_id == 1:
        # solvent = None
        background_tasks.add_task(predictions_two,solute)
        return {'success'}
    else:
        return "Give proper task_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your parameter as [`Optional`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/#optional-parameters). For instance:

```
from typing import Optional
...
async def predict(solvent: Optional[str] = None):
...
```